# Java or python which is better to do Automation using Selenium

Tags: selenium

Java or python which is better to do Automation using Selenium. since I don't have an idea about python, so please suggest me if python is better than Java for automation.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer is not only opinion based but also situation based. *Java* and *Python* both have its pros and cons (I will mention a few pros for both the variants) :

- **Java** (pros) :

  - Plenty of *documentation* and *tutorials* available online.
  - Enables you to integrate a wide range of tools. E.g. *TestNG* , *Maven* , *Jenkins* , *Cucumber* , etc
  - Widely accepted by customers.
- **Python** (pros) :

  - Unmatched where *Data Extraction* and *Data Science* is the major aim.
  - Syntax is not so *strict*.
  - Slowly and gradually gaining *popularity* and *market share*.

Comment: thanks for your answer. @DebanjanB

Comment: This shouldn't have been answered. It should have instead been closed as opinion based.